# Enabling The Emoji Keyboard in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, emoji

Emoji emoticons can be be an enhancing feature of a text-based conversation. Whilst having an android smartphone  it’s rather easy to add third-party emoji packs (due to the open source nature of android). iOS i believe is a more "closed" OS, things are *not that easy* (so i'm lead to believe).

However is there a hidden emoji feature within iOS 7 (without the need to jailbreak) that I can unleash on an iPhone 5/5S ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Tap on General.
3. Tap on International.
4. Tap on Keyboard.
5. Tap on Add New Keyboard.
6. Tap on Emoji.

To switch to it on the keyboard, tap the globe icon between `123` and the microphone icon.

I'd say that's easier than downloading a third-party anything on Android.  Plus it was included already 2 years ago with iOS 5.